# How to add Arabic font to Itext7 Xamarin form

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, itext7

I used the code below to add Arabic font to itext7 and it worked but when my pdf file is created, the Arabic words appear in separate letters and RIGHT_TO_LEFT not affect, Any help will be appreciated..

```
 public PdfFont GetFont(string filename, string fontName)
        {
            var assembly = typeof(ResultVehicleCheckList).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var fontStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.Assets.Fonts.{filename}");
     
            byte[] fontBytes;

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                fontStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                fontBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            return PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(fontBytes, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED, true);
        }


         // Initialize font (Use a font that supports Arabic characters)
         PdfFont   font = GetFont("arial.ttf", "arial");

          // Initialize table
 Table table1 = new Table(5, true);
            table1.SetBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            table1.SetWidth(MillimetersToPoints(185));
            table1.SetWidth(new UnitValue(UnitValue.PERCENT, 100));
```

Comment: https://kb.itextpdf.com/it5kb/how-to-create-persian-content-in-pdf

Comment: you need to load the pdfCalligraph module, which is available for iText 7.x and 8.x. The link above is for iText 5, and the answer below will change the direction, but need address any ligatures which Arabic requires.